# How to completely collapse sidebar in bs4Dash

Tags: javascript, r, shiny, sidebar, bs4dash

I need to fully (not partially) collapse the main sidebar (left) in my app with toggle button. I noticed there is an argument: `sidebar_fullCollapse` in `shinydashboardPlus`, that if set to TRUE will collapse the sidebar completely. However, we do not have this parameter in `bs4DashPage`.
Any help would be highly appreciated.

```
library(shiny)
library(bs4Dash)

shinyApp(
  ui = bs4DashPage(
    header = dashboardHeader(),
    body = dashboardBody(),
    sidebar = dashboardSidebar()
  ),
  server = function(input, output, session) {}
)
```

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I just found the answer to this question. There is a parameter in `bs4DashPage` by the name of `minified`. Setting this parameter to FALSE will collapse the sidebar completely.

```
library(shiny)
library(bs4Dash)

shinyApp(
  ui = bs4DashPage(
    header = dashboardHeader(),
    body = dashboardBody(),
    sidebar = dashboardSidebar(
      minified = F
    )
  ),
  server = function(input, output, session) {}
)
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is a sample picture which shows that the sidebar is completely collapsed.

[image]